# Await for function until it receives a callback in python async IO

Tags: python, bluetooth-lowenergy, python-asyncio, bluetooth-gatt

I have created a GATT Client in python using the Bleak Library. I subscribe to a notification characteristic and after when I get the callback in the notification handler function, I do a write to a characteristic.Until now, after I start the notification I used put a asyncio.sleep for 5 seconds and then I would do a write on the characteristic. But this is very flaky and there is no control over the code, so I want to wait until I receive a callback in notification handler function and when I get the response, I want to do the write. I am new to python async IO and I am not sure how to achieve this. Thanks for your time and effort.

Here is the Code:

```
import logging
import asyncio
import platform

from bleak import BleakClient
from bleak import _logger as logger
import time

from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

CHARACTERISTIC_UUID = "0000c305-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"
CHARACTERISTIC_UUID_WR = "0000c303-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"
CHARACTERISTIC_UUID_RD = "0000c301-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"

_executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(1)

async def notification_handler(sender, data):
    """Simple notification handler which prints the data received."""
    print("{0}: {1}".format(sender, data))
    print(hexdump(data, 16))


def hexdump(src, length=16):
        result = []
        digits = 4 if isinstance(src, str) else 2
        for i in range(0, len(src), length):
            s = src[i:i + length]
            hexa = " ".join(map("{0:0>2X}".format, src))
            text = "".join([chr(x) if 0x20 <= x < 0x7F else "." for x in s])
            result.append("%04X   %-*s   %s" % (i, length * (digits + 1), hexa, text))
        return "\n".join(result)

async def run(address, debug=False):
    if debug:
        import sys

        l = logging.getLogger("asyncio")
        l.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        h = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
        h.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        l.addHandler(h)
        logger.addHandler(h)



    async with BleakClient(address) as client:
        x = await client.is_connected()
        logger.info("Connected: {0}".format(x))

        bleDevice = client
        await client.start_notify(CHARACTERISTIC_UUID, notification_handler)


        # before: asyncio.sleep(5)


        # now: wait here until I the notification_hanlder get a callback, then do the write

        await client.write_gatt_char(CHARACTERISTIC_UUID_WR, [0xA6, 0x00, 0x02, 0xD0, 0x01, 0x77])
        
        await client.write_gatt_char(CHARACTERISTIC_UUID_WR, [0xA6])

        await client.write_gatt_char(CHARACTERISTIC_UUID_WR, [0xA7])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import os

    os.environ["PYTHONASYNCIODEBUG"] = str(1)
    address = (
        "48:23:35:00:14:be"  # <--- Change to your device's address here if you are using Windows or Linux
        if platform.system() != "Darwin"
        else "B9EA5233-37EF-4DD6-87A8-2A875E821C46"  # <--- Change to your device's address here if you are using macOS
    )

    # for i in range(5):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.set_debug(True)
    loop.run_until_complete(run(address, True))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll start with a side note. You appear to have picked some custom UUID values that are in the reserved range for Bluetooth SIG approved UUID's.  There is a helpful article on this at: https://www.novelbits.io/uuid-for-custom-services-and-characteristics/

On to your main question. I am only learning asyncio myself, but I took a look and have something running.
Your `write_gatt_char` commands were being executed when the client was initialised, not when the notification came in. Once it has done the writes then it was exiting.

I've modified your example to use a BBC micro:bit. When button "A" notification is sent this gets the Bleak client to send a random letter to the micro:bit. While a button "B" notification disconnects from the client.
I've moved the `write_gatt_char` into the notification code and used a `create_task` to execute the write.
To keep the client alive until button "B" is pressed on the micro:bit I've put a while loop in the client with a sleep to stop in completing. Suspect this is not the best way of doing it.

This is the example that worked for me:

```py
import logging
import asyncio
import platform
from random import randint

from bleak import BleakClient
from bleak import _logger as logger


BTN_A_UUID = "E95DDA90-251D-470A-A062-FA1922DFA9A8"
BTN_B_UUID = "E95DDA91-251D-470A-A062-FA1922DFA9A8"
LED_TXT_UUID = "E95D93EE-251D-470A-A062-FA1922DFA9A8"



async def run(address, debug=False):
    if debug:
        import sys

        l = logging.getLogger("asyncio")
        l.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        h = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
        h.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        l.addHandler(h)
        logger.addHandler(h)


    async with BleakClient(address) as client:
        x = await client.is_connected()
        logger.info("Connected: {0}".format(x))

        def btn_a_handler(sender, data):
            """Simple notification handler for btn a events."""
            print("{0}: {1}".format(sender, data))
            # Pick random letter to send
            if int.from_bytes(data, byteorder='little', signed=False) > 0:
                letter = [randint(99, 122)]
                loop.create_task(write_txt(letter))

        def btn_b_handler(sender, data):
            """Simple notification handler for btn b events."""
            print("{0}: {1}".format(sender, data))
            if int.from_bytes(data, byteorder='little', signed=False) > 0:
                loop.create_task(client.disconnect())

        async def write_txt(data):
            await client.write_gatt_char(LED_TXT_UUID,
                                         data)

        await client.start_notify(BTN_A_UUID, btn_a_handler)
        await client.start_notify(BTN_B_UUID, btn_b_handler)

        while await client.is_connected():
            await asyncio.sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    address = ("E9:06:4D:45:FC:8D")

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    # loop.set_debug(True)
    loop.run_until_complete(run(address, True))
```

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about the custom UUID. I have a custom GATT Server  and it has different characteristics for read, write and notify. So, when I start_notify on the notification UUID , after 2 seconds I get the callback and dependent on the callback I have to perform the write.So, once I start the notification, I will keep getting callbacks on the notification_handler and based on that I have to writes on the subsequent UUID. So basically, I have to keep the notification_handler alive and keep doing writes until I disconnect.

Comment: Is your last comment a question? Did I misunderstand something? I had understood that your code needs to receive a notification and based on the data in that notification, you write to a different characteristic/UUID. I thought that was what my example did. Your original code was disconnecting and finishing before the notification was received and didn't do the writes based on the information in the notification. Was that what you intended?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, this worked after some minor changes. Thanks for your help man. It all works fast and without any problems.